# Generate a dynamical table based on TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I'm looking to create a 3*x table based on the number of questions using TikZ, as shown in the following illustration.

[image]

I've defined a method, and the code is as follows:

```
\newcounter{colnumber}
% Define Chinese numbers
    \newcommand{\chinesenumber}[1]{%
      \ifcase#1\or 一\or 二\or 三\or 四\or 五\or 六\or 七\or 八\or 九\or 十\fi
    }

    % Define the command to create the table
    \newcommand{\createtable}[1]{%
      \setcounter{colnumber}{#1} % Set the number of columns
      % \pgfmathsetmacro{\cellwidth}{\textwidth/\thecolnumber} % Calculate the width of each cell
      \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\fontsize{14}{18}\selectfont}]
        \tikzset{cell/.style={rectangle, draw=black, minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=2.8cm, align=center, inner sep=0pt}}
        % Draw the column titles
        \node[cell] at (2.8,0) {Num}; % First column title
        \foreach \x in {2,...,\thecolnumber}
        \node[cell] at (\x*2.8,0) {\chinesenumber{\numexpr\x-1}}; % Chinese number column titles
        \node[cell] at (\thecolnumber*2.8+2.8,0) {Total score}; % Last column title
        % Draw the rows
        \node[cell] at (2.8,-1.5) {Score}; % First column second row
        \node[cell] at (2.8,-3) {Teacher}; % First column third row
        \foreach \y in {1,...,3}
        \foreach \x in {2,...,\thecolnumber}
        \node[cell] at (\x*2.8,-\y*1.5) {}; % Fill other cells
        \foreach \y in {2,...,3}
        \node[cell] at (\thecolnumber*2.8+2.8,-\y*1.5) {}; % Fill the last column's other cells
        % Draw the outer frame
        \draw (1.4,0.75) rectangle (\thecolnumber*2.8+4.2,-4.5); % Adjust size based on rows and columns
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
```

When I use the command (`\createtable{4}`) in the main.tex, I can generate the table as shown below.

[image]

However, it seems to have two extra rows. Additionally, when there are too many questions, the table extends beyond the page. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

A macro `\tblrbody` is initialized with `\tl_new:N \tblrbody`.

The content is collected with `\tl_build_put_right:Nn`. This process is started with `\tl_build_begin:N` and ended with `\tl_build_end:N`. Thereafter, the option `expand=\tblrbody` is given to the `tblr` environment where `\tblrbody` is placed.

The number of rows depends on the number after `\int_step_inline:nn`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \tblrbody
\tl_build_begin:N \tblrbody
\int_step_inline:nn { 4 }
  {
    \tl_build_put_right:Nn \tblrbody { #1 & & \\ }
  }
\tl_build_end:N \tblrbody
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{tblr}[expand=\tblrbody]{
  hlines,
  vlines
}
Number & Score & Teacher\\
\tblrbody
Total score & & \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```